# Wubi Grub Prompt "Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported"

Tags: grub2, bash, system-installation, wubi

I just installed Ubuntu today with WUBI. After installing, the first time I tried to boot it, it gave me a screen with this grub prompt:

```
Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. For the first word, TAB 
lists possible command completions. Anywhere else TAB lists 
possible device or file completions.

GRUB>
```

I tried repeatedly to reboot, and no luck. What is wrong?

Comment: You need to run chkdsk and then look for the root.disk. http://ubuntu-with-wubi.blogspot.ca/2011/08/missing-rootdisk.html

Comment: Try the steps provided [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/198550/33871). Despite the question asked there was a little different, if it doesn't work for you it should at least provide more info about your specific problem.

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE!!! http://askubuntu.com/questions/366001/ubuntu-13-10-grub-2-0

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps below one by one.

1. Boot from the Ubuntu Live cd/usb and select "try ubuntu".
2. When the desktop is loaded, download the [boot script](http://bootinfoscript.sourceforge.net/). It contains script and a changelog file.
3. Now `cd` to the directory of the extracted zip file.
4. `sudo bash boot_info_script.sh`
   The above steps should get you through.

Comment: How is this an answer? It's just asking to use to the boot_info_script to provide a troubleshooting log!

Comment: After performing the above 4 steps It worked for me, you can save the log file which is returned after the last step for diagnosing if the problem still remains intact.

Answer (score 0):

When the machine first froze, did you just switch it off, because you did not know how to regain control? If so, you have probably corrupted the file system and that has apparently prevented grub finding its files.

The first thing to try is to boot from the livecd, open a terminal, type `su` to become **root**, enter the root password (`root` for a standard livecd) when prompted, and then run `fsck -fy /dev/sdax` where `ax` is the letter and number of your pclos partitions. To find out which they are you can use `fdisk -l` (that's a lower-case 'L'). You don't need to (and can't, in fact) `fsck` the swap, but the `/` and `/home` or whatever you have need to be done. They must be unmounted, but should be by default with the livecd. If not, use `umount /dev/sdax` to unmount them.