# Problems Installing Ubuntu on Notebook

Tags: 12.04, installation, grub2, usb

I installed Manjaro from a live usb, the set up went fine but I wasnt a fan after using it for a bit. I found Ubuntu easier on the command line to use so I wanted to go back.

However, now I would like to return back to Ubuntu, yet when booting via usb, I hit the 'Minimal bask -like editing' Line and can no longer go any further.

I have tried multiple live usb distros, but hit the same problem, yet the Manjaro live usb works fine.

Could somebody help me in removing 'everything' to allow an Ubuntu install)

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Could you be more explicit?

Comment: well simply put, I can boot Manjaro via usb, but I can not boot anything else via usb as it hits the Grub (Minimal BASH-like line editing) screen

Comment: manjaro probably messed up kernels...but it's an ARCH derivative so we can not help you there.

Comment: and a possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/180459/wubi-grub-prompt-minimal-bash-like-line-editing-is-supported

Comment: Thats the thing, no longer want to use Manjaro and want to install ubuntu/mint. simply put, I want to know how to fully remove everything (Kernals, ect) that will then allow me to boot an ubuntu usb

Comment: Your original question is unclear.  I suggest you edit its title to "Problems Installing Ubuntu on Notebook" then edit the text to say you have installed "Manjaro" but want to remove it and install Ubuntu instead.  Include details of your hardware and the problems you are having. Should get a better answer this way.

Comment: Warren, I have took up your suggestion and re-writ the question! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may seem fairly basic but if you can boot Manjaro from the USB you should be able to get gparted and just reformat your drive, since your booting off the USB, Once the hard drive is formatted, you should be able to then try any other distro you would like.  I'm still a little unclear of "no longer want to use Manjaro and want to install ubuntu/mint. simply put, I want to know how to fully remove everything (Kernals, ect) that will then allow me to boot an ubuntu usb"?  Are you trying to run mint as a live USB and then install to hard drive?  or are you trying to install mint onto the USB?

Comment: Hi there, I tried that a number of times, however I managed to get it resolved. There seemed to be a problem with how Manjaro set up the MBR. ran # dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdc bs=512 count=1 to remove the MBR and then after installing lilo used sudo lilo -M /dev/sda mbr This sorted my problem! Gparted wouldn't for me anyway, remove the MBR

Comment: Accepted your answer as you are the only person to actually suggest an answer and not be an uptight arse.